# Win10 boot loop, no admin user, can't boot from usb

Tags: windows-10, boot, windows-update

It's a Lenovo Yoga 300 with a 32Gb SSD and Windows 10. After a few times of unsuccessful anniversary update process (not enough space) I decided to do a reset with windows 10 system reset tool. It couldn't make it then I tried to do a full wipe reset and that wasn't successful either.

After this second reset attempt I'm with a windows 10 boot loop. I've read many suggestions on similar problems but nether helped. What I have already tried:

- With the reset button I was able to open Windows System Recovery tool, where I had several options:

  - Reset this PC. (Same result, didn't do anything)
  - Under advanced options there are severe usable options but all of them says "you need to sign in as an administrator to continue. but there aren't any administrator accounts on this pc." - so I cannot use any of them. (Couldn't start a command prompt, Startup repair, system restore)
- Downloaded a windows 10 image from ms and tried to boot from usb device without success.

My last idea was that I have mistakenly downloaded a 64bit image and this is why I can't boot from it. So now I'm getting the 32bit image. Btw I can't even set the bios to boot from usb. The boot priority order has no USB option. It has only one option that is saying Windows Boot Loader.

Any suggestions are more that welcome but please don't suggest me such thing that I can add an admin account in windows, because I cannot boot into windows.

Comment: First step, enable the built-in Administrator, I wrote a detailed answer on how to do that.  Your problem can't be solved without the installation disk

Comment: @Ramhound Where can I find the detailed answer about enabling the built in admin? I have a downloaded win10 iso written to an usb key with rufus. I can not boot from it.

Comment: I submitted an answer to a question.  What does your research say

Comment: @Ramhound Nothing. That's why I am asking because I thought that you answered to my question but forgot to submit it. [Search1](http://superuser.com/search?q=user%3A83283+%5Bwindows-10%5D+administrator)
[Seacrh2](http://superuser.com/search?q=user%3A83283+admin) [This is related but I cannot boot into windows.](http://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer/1024221#1024221)

Comment: I submitted an answer that explains how to enable the built-in Administrator.  That's the first step to solving your problem

Comment: @Ramhound Can you please give me a link to that answer?

Comment: I don't have one handy.

Comment: I believe [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer/1024221#1024221) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10 recovery without local administrator](https://superuser.com/questions/1120601/windows-10-recovery-without-local-administrator)