# Windows 10 cannot boot after installing Ubuntu

Tags: windows-10, boot, multi-boot

I have a PC running Windows 10 on which I recently installed Ubuntu so I can dual boot into either. I allocated disk space to Ubuntu in a similar manner to [this image](https://assets.ubuntu.com/v1/6d01bd8c-download-desktop-install-ubuntu-desktop_5.jpg).

Several days later, a screen appeared when I booted Windows saying "Repairing disk errors. This may take over an hour to complete." For the few days prior to this, Windows worked fine alongside Ubuntu. I recall getting one blue screen about a day before the problem started, but I didn't think anything of it at the time so I didn't take note of the error code.

After about an hour this screen went away and the computer booted into Ubuntu, despite having selected Windows in the bootloader. Now, whenever I try to boot into Windows I get a screen with the Windows logo saying "Preparing automatic repair", after which I get [this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zn66q.jpg) giving the following error:

> You need to sign in as an administrator to continue, but there aren't any administrator accounts on this PC

The account I normally use is an administrator account, but this does not show up in this menu.

After clicking the "can't see your account?" button it prompts me to restart, which brings me to the same place if I try to boot into Windows. Ubuntu is still working as expected. I am able to access the files that were in the Windows partition through Ubuntu.

Holding Shift+F8 during boot does not do anything, but I can still press other keys to get into my BIOS menu, etc.

Comment: Something is definitely wrong. I did dual boot a couple different times and finally turned an unused laptop into a Linux OS for UC project school work. To me dual boot is kind of novel. I wouldn't do it again. I'd advise anyone to just get a used laptop. There are a number of reasons this could be wrong; too many to guess. Software issues. Partition issues. It's a guessing game at this point. You can also install Linux flavours on top of windows Virtually rather than a dual boot. And for getting into bios it's F8 only or ESC. I can't recall which is which but both work for different reasons.

Comment: Most likely this was caused by a disk error. You could try booting from a Linux rescue disk and running a disk check and repair. If you have a Windows rescue disk, you should be able to use that to recover Windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10 recovery without local administrator](https://superuser.com/questions/1120601/windows-10-recovery-without-local-administrator)