# Can't access troubleshooting tools

Tags: windows, windows-10

I want to refresh/reset my PC. I go to advanced startup and choose restart now and it reboots my PC to the troubleshooting tools. I choose the option to refresh my PC (keeps files) but it shows that I need to sign in as an administrator and says “but there aren’t any administrator accounts on this PC.”  I already enabled the hidden administrator account of Windows 10 and my other account also has admin privileges but it doesn't show any of these accounts.

I searched for a solution to my problem and a guide pointed that I should choose the "Command Prompt" option instead of the "Refresh/Reset PC" option. I tried to follow that guide and the same problem occurs showing that I need to login as an administrator.

[image: problem encountered]

My PC is currently running Windows 10 64-bit. I am also currently downloading the Windows Fall Creators Update hoping that this update is the solution to my problem.

Comment: Did you upgrade to Windows 10 1709 successfully? The Media Creation Tool is also available to upgrade to Windows 10 1709. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: @KarenHu I'm still downloading the update at the moment hoping that the update will fix this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10 recovery without local administrator](https://superuser.com/questions/1120601/windows-10-recovery-without-local-administrator)