# filezilla and the corresponding files into a saved - crypted folder

Tags: linux, filezilla

I run filezilla on a win 7 notebook  that is sometimes used by my colleagues.

I want to have filezilla contents in a saved environment - and want to make sure that no body else has access to the server.

Should I put filezilla contents in hidden folder or in a folder that is encrypted and that gives access only after a password is given.

This option can be realized by the encryption methods for folders that is given by Winrar. In other words - with winrar I can set up a folder that has only access for those that know the password.

Can I do this like so1?

Comment: I do not see how WinRAR can help here. You should use Windows file encryption.

Comment: Honestly, if your computer has a password protection to login. THAT should solve your hidden or encrypted dilemma. Why would you need to encrypt something that other people (FTP users) have access to anyway.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can't share or network an encrypted folder or files. I've never heard of such a thing. But I could be wrong.

Comment: hello Martin - hello sickest man thanks for the answers - question how to use the windows file-encryption!? Love to hear from you

Comment: See https://superuser.com/q/244844/213663